# C++ Syntax question - passing a constructor and also an argument in parenthesis to another function?

Tags: c++, function, syntax

I hope this isn't too stupid of a question, but I happened upon some C++ syntax I'm trying to wrap my head around, and wanted to confirm with all of you experts out there.

Here's the code in question:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-CPP-Multithreading/blob/master/Chapter01/ch01_mt_example.cpp

Specially this call:

`static thread_local mt19937 generator(hash<thread::id>()(this_thread::get_id()));`

I get the gist of what the code is doing; it's easy to look up the different class references, or simply run the code, but I wanted to understand the syntax there.

Looking into the C++ reference:

- `mt19937` 's constructor takes a `result_type`, defined as an alias of the first class template parameter.
- I understand that `hash<thread::id>` will give us the default hash function for `thread::id` types, which we would then pass `this_thread::get_id()` to. The C++ reference says that `hash::operator()`
  returns a hash value for its argument, as a value of type `size_t` where `size_t` is an unsigned integral type.

My questions:

1. Why is the class template type for `mt19937` not defined?
2. Why are we calling `hash<thread::id>()` with no argument, but then putting `(this_thread::get_id())` right beside it?

I guess I'm confused, because I would have expected this line to read:

`static thread_local mt19937<size_t> generator(hash<thread::id>(this_thread::get_id()));`

Can someone help explain why it is not?

Thanks!

I am trying to understand the code above; I went through the C++ references, but there is syntactic elements I don't understand which are difficult to learn from the reference.

Comment: *"My questions:"*. One question by question.

Comment: `hash<thread::id>()(this_thread::get_id())` is mostly equivalent to `hash<thread::id> temp_variable{}; temp_variable/*.operator()*/(this_thread::get_id());`

Comment: Richard: Do you want me to explain anything in more detail in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the class template type for `mt19937` not defined?

`std::mt19937` is not a class template. It's a typedef for:

```cpp
std::mersenne_twister_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 32, 624, 397, 31, 0x9908b0df, 11,
                              0xffffffff, 7, 0x9d2c5680, 15, 0xefc60000, 18,
                              1812433253>
```

So, no template parameters have to be supplied.

> Why are we calling `hash<thread::id>()` with no argument, but then putting `(this_thread::get_id())` right beside it?

`std::hash<thread::id>` is a class and not a function.

The first set of parentheses contains the arguments to the `std::hash<thread::id>` constructor. With no arguments, it's default constructed.

The second set of parentheses is the *call* to `operator()` on the `std::hash<thread::id>` instance - and that's where the thread id is supplied.